# MySQL select count by value

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have this mysql table:

```
DATE | VALUE
```

and I wish to become a select which shows me this information as:

```
DATE | COUNT TOTAL | COUNT VAL=1 | COUNT VAL=2
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. You should add that tag, and then post what you've tried so far, explain what didn't work as you expected, and then we can try and help you figure out why. We're not going to do the work for you, because you won't learn anything that way.

Comment: Well I can create seperate queries (one for a total overview, one for VAL1 and VAL2). But I can't get them combined:
SELECT date, COUNT(*)
FROM payments
WHERE paymentProviderId = 2
GROUP BY YEAR( DATE ) , MONTH(DATE ) , DAY(DATE )

(and no it's not a homework assignment)

Comment: I have this exact question right now, and it is *not* homework in my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT date,
       COUNT(*),
       COUNT( IF( value = 1, 1, NULL ) ),
       COUNT( IF( value = 2, 1, NULL ) )
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Is there any neater way? Not including the hardcorded value.

Answer (score 2):

I think with `SUM()` you can get neater code. Since it sums the values respective expression for row.

```
SELECT date,
   COUNT(*),
   SUM( value = 1 ),
   SUM( value = 2 )
FROM my_table
```

Official Documentation can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum).

Comment: Thats the more cleaner way i guess

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(*) AS `COUNT TOTAL`, 
  COUNT(CASE `value` WHEN 1 THEN `value` END) AS `COUNT VAL=1`
  COUNT(CASE `value` WHEN 2 THEN `value` END) AS `COUNT VAL=2`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `date`
```

The CASE expressions will be null when there is no match.  Nulls are not counted by `COUNT()`.

I imagine you might want a dynamic number of columns, one column for each value found in the data.  **This is not possible in SQL.**  The columns must be known at the time you write the query.

So you have two options to get subtotals per value:

- First query the distinct values from all rows of `value` and construct an SQL query dynamically, appending one column in the select-list for each distinct value you want to report.  Then run this SQL query.
- Alternatively, fetch all the rows as rows.  Count the subtotals per value in application code.

One further alternative is to count subtotals by groups, and include totals:

```
SELECT `value`, `date, COUNT(*) AS `COUNT SUBTOTAL`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `value`, `date` WITH ROLLUP
```

But that doesn't report the subtotals in columns as you requested, it reports the subtotals in rows.