# Slow count query with large data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

**points**

```
id
name
```

**products**

```
id
name
point_id
```

**verifies**

```
id
name
product_id
result
```

When I create product, I need to give it a point, and after I verify a product, I will save the result in verifies table, now my client want to run points to count each different verify result of point, that's how I do.

```
SELECT `p`.`name`,
(SELECT COUNT(`pr`.`id`) FROM `products` `pr` INNER JOIN `verifies` `v` ON `pr`.`id' = `v`.`product_id` WHERE `pr`.`point_id` = `p`.`p_id` AND `v`.`result` = 1) AS `verify_result1`,
(SELECT COUNT(`pr`.`id`) FROM `products` `pr` INNER JOIN `verifies` `v` ON `pr`.`id' = `v`.`product_id` WHERE `pr`.`point_id` = `p`.`p_id` AND `v`.`result` = 2) AS `verify_result2`,
(SELECT COUNT(`pr`.`id`) FROM `products` `pr` INNER JOIN `verifies` `v` ON `pr`.`id' = `v`.`product_id` WHERE `pr`.`point_id` = `p`.`p_id` AND `v`.`result` = 3) AS `verify_result3`,
(SELECT COUNT(`pr`.`id`) FROM `products` `pr` INNER JOIN `verifies` `v` ON `pr`.`id' = `v`.`product_id` WHERE `pr`.`point_id` = `p`.`p_id` AND `v`.`result` = 4) AS `verify_result4`,
(SELECT COUNT(`pr`.`id`) FROM `products` `pr` INNER JOIN `verifies` `v` ON `pr`.`id' = `v`.`product_id` WHERE `pr`.`point_id` = `p`.`p_id` AND `v`.`result` = 5) AS `verify_result5`
FROM `points` `p`
```

The result is correct, but it's very slow because points table has over 3000 data, how to make it faster?

Comment: You can wrap this into one query, see this SO answer for "[count by value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7367302/772086)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `p`.`name`,
  COUNT( IF( `v`.`result` = 1, 1, NULL ) ) As Result1,
  COUNT( IF( `v`.`result` = 2, 1, NULL ) ) As Result2,
  COUNT( IF( `v`.`result` = 3, 1, NULL ) ) As Result3,
  COUNT( IF( `v`.`result` = 4, 1, NULL ) ) As Result4,
  COUNT( IF( `v`.`result` = 5, 1, NULL ) ) As Result5,
FROM `points` `p`
  INNER JOIN `products` `pr` ON `p`.`p_id` = `pr`.`point_id`
  INNER JOIN `verifies` `v` ON `pr`.`id' = `v`.`product_id`
GROUP BY `p`.`name`
```

Comment: If verifies table have more condition like type = 2, how to do it?

Comment: You want the first parameter of `IF()` to resolve to `True`, so instead of `result = 1`, use `result = 1 AND type = 2`. See a similar example with [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9112102).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUM` also instead of `COUNT` like:

```
SELECT `p`.`name`
        , SUM(IF(result=1,1,0)) as verify_result1
        , SUM(IF(result=2,1,0)) as verify_result2
        , SUM(IF(result=3,1,0)) as verify_result3
        , SUM(IF(result=4,1,0)) as verify_result4
        , SUM(IF(result=5,1,0)) as verify_result5
FROM points p
INNER JOIN products pr ON p.id = pr.point_id
INNER JOIN verifies v ON pr.id = v.product_id
GROUP BY p.name
```